# How to use @Id with String Type in JPA / Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one entity which contains primary key of type string. This entity model is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

@Id
@Column(name="PR_KEY", unique=true)
private String prKey;

....
....

}
```

But I am facing issue saying TypeMismatch.

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Long
```

Comment: how was defined the method `getPrKey()`? are you sure that it's returning a `String` object?

Comment: Yes, it returns String only.

Comment: any progress @Kailas ? its strange that is seems to be so hard to simply have a String Id. I have the same problem.

Comment: I think you are using a wrong json key for field. Remember the json key is always what is mentions in java class. Not the Column name.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you don't specify an id generation strategy, Hibernate will use `GenerationType.AUTO`. This will result in any of

> AUTO - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the
>   underlying DB.

If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-hibernate), you'll notice all of those generate ids of type `long`, `short` or `int`, not of type `String`.

Say you wanted a `String` UUID as an id, you could use

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "PR_KEY")
private String prKey;
```

Comment: Value of this key is provided by some other entity in my program. I dont want it to be generated automatically. I think GeneratedValue annotation will make it generated value. Please correct me

Answer (score 3):

Check the PR_KEY data type in database table. This problem might occur, if the column is of type Number and you are trying to map the same to String in your entity.

Same applies to the coulmn with generated Ids.

Comment: It is VARCHAR2 in database.

Comment: @Kailas I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to use string as primary key by using **strategy = "uuid"** in the annotation `@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")`

This will generates a unique 36-character id

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ToDoClass {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
     
    //...
      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When String is used as a id, same type should be used also when finding entity via Session/EntityManager:

Instead of providing Long:

```
Long key = 1L;
MyEntity me = session.get(MyEntity.class, key); 
//or 
MyEntity me = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, key);
```

String should be given:

```
String key = "1";
MyEntity me = session.get(MyEntity.class, key); 
//or 
MyEntity me = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, key);
```