# Hibernate - How to set an object which has pk and fk to be VARCHAR in database?

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, persistence

I have two entities, the first of which is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="E_CMS_CFG")
public class E_CMS_CFG extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)//, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "CFG_TYPE", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "CFG_TYPE", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(32)"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "CFG_TYPE_ID", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
        })
    private E_CMS_CFG_TYPE cfgType;
```

The second entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="E_CMS_CFG_TYPE")
public class E_CMS_CFG_TYPE extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CFG_TYPE", length = 32)
    private String cfgType;
```

In the first entity, I use `columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(32)"` on the `CFG_TYPE` column; however, in the database, it is creating a `cfg_type` integer column.  Is it possible to create a `VARCHAR cfg_type` column and not an integer?  And if it is, how? I am using Sqlite 3.8.10.1 version.

**UPDATE:** 
The link did not help, but if I replace in `E_CMS_CFG` the `@Id` with `@NaturalId (mutable = false)`, it works, but it creates it without a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the natural id annotation here. For example:

```
@NaturalId (mutable = false)
@Column(name = "CFG_TYPE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 32)
private String cfgType;
```

But I think you would still have to provide an id property and that would still be an integer value/column in your database.

I think this Question is a duplicate of ["how to use id with string type in jpa hibernate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate)

I hope that helps!

Comment: @FAndrew see my edit. I think your question may be a duplicate. Just follow the Link I've provided.

Comment: did not helped me the link, but if I replace in E_CMS_CFG the Id with NaturalId (mutable = false) it works but it creates without pk

Comment: OK this is how I meant it. Yeah I think you would still have to provide an extra Id property which hibernate can use as pk internally. This will still be an integer value.

Comment: Yeah now I do with NaturalId hoply in future did not give commplications