# How should I use FindOne with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I just started learning Spring Boot by reading the book *Spring Boot in Action* and  I am copying the examples of the book, trying to run them myself but I have a problem using findOne. The project is supposed to be a simple Reading List.
Here is the code :

The interface:

```
public interface ReaderRepository extends JpaRepository<Reader, String> {
}
```

The Reader class:

```
@Entity
public class Reader implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String fullname;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }
    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    // UserDetails methods
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("READER"));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ReaderRepository readerRepository;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('READER')")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(new UserDetailsService() {
                    @Override
                    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                        return readerRepository.findOne(username);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

And the error:

[error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtA73.png)

I hope someone can help me because I am lost.
Thank you.

Comment: Check your imports on ReaderRepository you might been importing the wrong 'Reader'

Comment: Code seems to fine. As @JorgeC  suggested just check with your import. Probably you can perform clean-build.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I changed my import, still same error. When i try to build i get this 
Error:(38, 48) java: method findOne in interface org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: org.springframework.data.domain.Example<S>
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) S
    (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.springframework.data.domain.Example<S>)

Comment: which spring boot version are you using?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.0.5

Comment: I might be wrong but, `@Id` annotation by default expects a numeric type, `int`, `long` or `short` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate). You can use `String` in `@Id` annotation if it is an `UUID` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

`java: method findOne in interface org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor<T> cannot be applied to given types; required: org.springframework.data.domain.Example<S> found: java.lang.String reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) S (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.springframework.data.domain.Example<S>)`

It's very straight forward. You need to pass `Example` object here. Here is a code.

```
Reader  r = new Reader().
r.setUserName("somename");

readerRepository.findOne(Example.of(r));
```

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't working either.
I used getOne instead of findOne