# xHow can I have @Id string for CrudRepository in Spring with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-hateoas

The problem is that I am getting an exception using `@RepositoryRestResource` for my `UserRepository` that extends `JpaRepository`.

The reason for that is that `findById` is only accepting `Long` or `Int` types by default, even I have

`@Id String id;` and not `@Id Int id` in my entity definition.

I have tried searching StackOverflow and Google, but haven't found any solutions.

The error message is as follows:

`"Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '3175433272470683'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"3175433272470683\""`

I want to make it work with a

`@Id String id;`

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advances. It's a big privilege to ask questions here.

The Entity class:

```java
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name = "users")
public class XmppUser {
    @Id
    private java.lang.String username;

    private String password;
    private String serverkey;
    private String salt;
    private int iterationcount;
    private Date created_at;

    //    @Formula("ST_ASTEXT(coordinates)")
//    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry")
//    private Point coordinates;
    //    private Point coordinates;
    private String full_name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = true)
    private XmppLast xmppLast;
```

Comment: Could you post the entity class code?

Comment: Just posted an entity class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must change the type of the ID type parameter in the repository to match with the id attribute type on your entity.

From the Spring docs:

> ```
> Interface Repository<T,ID>
> Type Parameters:
>   T - the domain type the repository manages    
>   ID - the type of the id of the entity the repository manages
> ```

Based on

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name = "users")
public class XmppUser {
    @Id
    private java.lang.String username;
    //...

    }
```

It should be

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<XmppUser, String> {
    //..
    }
```

See:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById(ID)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html

Comment: Just added this to the repository:

```@Override
    Optional<XmppUser> findById(String integer);```

Comment: It says: `method does not override method from its superclass`

Comment: @DavidJones , I’ve added an example

Comment: @admiz635 that's exactly what I have, and inside it: `@Override Optional<XmppUser> findById(String integer);`

Comment: Oh, my bad. Just noticed that the second type parameter to `CrudRepository<XmppUser, String>` is a String! That solved the problem!

Great job @admiz635!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "PR_KEY")
private String prKey;
```

If you want to read more about this subject you could begin looking throw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate)

Comment: Tried. It doesn't work. Same error. Just tried again.

Answer (score 0):

according to the latest version of spring data jpa(2.1.10 GA), you can use it like
[image]

here is the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Comment: @DavidJones so your spring data jpa version is?

Comment: Version: 2.1.9.RELEASE

Comment: @DavidJones try it like this:@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. I expected Spring to have fewer issues. That's the second bug I found today.

Answer (score 0):

JpaRepository is a special case of CrudRepository. Both JpaRepository and CrudRepository declare two type parameters, T and ID. You will need to supply these two class types. For example,

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<XmppUser, java.lang.String> {
//..
}
```

or

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<XmppUser, java.lang.String> {
//..
}
```

Notice that the second type `java.lang.String` must match the type of the primary key attribute. In this case, you cannot specify it as `String` or `Integer`, but it is `java.lang.String` instead.

Try not to name a customized class as `String`. It is a bad practice to use the same class name as already present in the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an approach to solve this problem.

Let's say, Site is our @Entity.

```
@Id
private String id;

getters setters
```

**then you can invoke findById as follow**

```
 Optional<Site> site = getSite(id);
```

Note: this worked for me, I hope it will help someone.