# How to update specific entity/row in jpa entity manager

Tags: java, angular, rest, microservices

I would like someone to help me on how to update row with entity manager. Here is a table ex, in angular where data is sent to rest service:
**app.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let myCar of cars$ | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
            <td>{{ (p - 1) * count + i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.price}}</td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="fillForm(myCar)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Edit
                </button></td>
</tr>
```

**carsDTO.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "price")
private String price;
```

**service.java**

```
public carsDTO updateCar(carDTO cars){
  TypedQuery<myquerycalss> query = entitymanager.createNamedQuery("sqlName", 
  myquerycalss.class);
  // I need help to complete this update method
  // Maybe no need to first find by id, the row gets update based on @id 
  // on the name
}
```

**resource.java**

```
@PUT
@Path("/updatecars")
public Response updateCar(){
    // no preblem here
}
```

Note: You can see that in the app.html I have ID generated but my jave class just name and price variables.

What is the best approach to update a chosen entity, that is, fields of database record, in my service.java? My resouces url is without parameter, that is URL: **.../updatecars**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resource needs to receive the car selected and changed in the frontend.
You can change it to receive inside the request body, using this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/updatecars")
public Response updateCar(@RequestBody() carDTO car){
    // here you call the service, passing the car as parameter
    service.updateCar(car);
}
```

Inside your angular component, you have to put the car selected in the http request. Something like this:

```
saveCar(car: carDTO){
    return this.httpBase.put(this.url, car, this.options)
        .map(dados => dados.json());  // handle the return here....
}
```

Inside your service:

```
public carsDTO updateCar(carDTO cars) {
    TypedQuery<myquerycalss> query = entitymanager.createNamedQuery("sqlName", myquerycalss.class);
    query.setParameter("name", cars.getName());
    query.setParameter("price", cars.getPrice());
    query.executeUpdate();
    ...
}
```

I'm assuming that your named query SQL is like this:

```
UPDATE cars SET price = :price WHERE name = :name
```

Comment: There is no problem with in the angular part. Please what does the "..." mean, can you give example? Thanks

Comment: I included the service method, with an example. I assumed that your SQL has these parameters.. please, post your SQL in your question...

Comment: I am not sure he can update directly without having something like this on the id since id is string in this case  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate

Comment: @henriqueor my SQL looks: UPDATE carTable ct SET ct.PRICE = price WHERE ct.NAME = name. It was pretty much like in your example.