# Java @Id without @column(nullable=false)

Tags: java, hibernate

Am i right that @Id annotation add two constraints in database:

- nullable=false
- unique=true

?
I saw a lot of examples in the Internet with syntax like

```
@Id
@Column(name="xxx",nullable=false)
BigInteger id
```

It is correct? Do i really need this nullable=false?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20603638/1531971

Comment: Mentioned about @Id annotation but no answer for my particular question

Comment: The 'name=XXX' is reason enough, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you are right. If you use hibernate schema generation mechanism, all @Id columns in the database will be NOT NULL and have unique index by default.

In the other hand, `@Column(nullable=false)` declaration is absolutely meaningless if you create the schema any other way.

Answer (score 0):

One reason you might see the two together is for the *name* attribute on `@Column`. It's *name* attribute lets you explicitly choose the name of the column in the resulting table, in cases where the default name that JPA provides. I will at times use `@Column` solely for that purpose, just so I can give my column a certain name.

As for the *nullable* attribute, I agree with you. It's worthless in that case.