# Problems with @GeneratedValue in the H2 database

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, spring-data

Hello StackOverflow Community, I have a problem with the annotation `@GenerateValue`. I want that JPA generates the values for my ID column. But I have another column where people can write some sort of tasks (todo list).

My code seems like this:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
```

and I have a SQL data file that write some data at the beginning in my h2 database:

```sql
    INSERT INTO task VALUES(1, 'go to the gym');
    INSERT INTO task VALUES(2, 'eat with tom');
    INSERT INTO task VALUES(3, 'meetup');
    INSERT INTO task VALUES(4, 'doing some homeworks');
    INSERT INTO task VALUES(5, 'doing some exercise');
    INSERT INTO task VALUES(6, 'studying with Mat');
```

my problem is, when I delete the integer values on my SQL data file, my compiler says always that I have to declare an id for the tasks, but I thought the `@GenerateValue` automatically generate the id's for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note:** Use `@GeneratedValue` on Primary Key Cols

You have to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
or
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`
When your strategy is **IDENTITY** you don't need to define a sequence in your database.
But when your strategy is **SEQUENCE** make sure that you have sequence on database level.

Also, when using auto-generated ids, don't specify them explicitly when inserting.

Correct insert query when you have primary key column in table:

```
INSERT INTO task(description) VALUES('go to the gym');
```

> but I thought the "@GenerateValue" automatically generate the id's for me?

It's a not the correct assumption, Hibernate just uses ids provided by db. To get it to work you need to create index/sequence for your primary key column.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446726/792580
to know more about Generation Strategies

Comment: Using Hibernate and H2, I have tested strategies `AUTO`, `IDENTITY` and `SEQUENCE`. Looking at the generated SQL script for table creation, I've seen that using `IDENTITY` adds `generated by default as identity` in the script.
For both `AUTO` and `SEQUENCE`, nothing is added in the script, same as if `@GeneratedValue` wasn't there.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing up sql and hibernate. `@GeneratedValue` is declared in your java code, so that hibernate knows, that when you're persisting an entity without an id, it should be generated by given `strategy`.

On the other hand you tried to make insertions using sql without passing primary key, so you're explicitly said, that it should be `NULL`, which is clearly against the constraint.

Comment: uff, I understand. Thank you

Comment: @DominiqueRosario no problem, consider upvoting if you fount the answer helpful;>

Answer (score 2):

When using GenerationType.AUTO, the persistence provider will choose the default generation strategy for the database. H2 uses by default a sequence starting at 1 and incrementing by 50. Therefore using GenerationType.AUTO or GenerationType.SEQUENCE with H2 should have the same result.
I think you only need to adjust the insert code. In SQL, if you do not enter all the values, you will need to specify the columns.
For example: "INSERT INTO task (name) VALUES ('go to the gym').

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, the incrementing by 50 threw me off. What is the rationale behind the incrementing by 50?