# ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column | Hibernate ORM

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, oracle19c

I am trying to insert in a oracle view using JPA. JPA generates below SQL statement-

```
insert into home_view (id, email, first_name, last_name) values (default, ?, ?, ?)
```

And when it executes query, Oracle DB throws below error-

```
ORA-32575: Explicit column default is not supported for modifying views
```

As per my understanding above query can not work with view because we can not insert into a view if its underlying table column is IDENTITY column.

Do we have any option in hibernate which helps exclusion of identity column while saving object to DB?

Note- I do not want to use raw SQL statement to insert my object.

I used GenerationType.SEQUENCE strategy and it is working fine, but only problem is I have to provide sequence name. I do not want to provide hard coded sequence name in Java Entity.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: remove column name id and default from the query, that should work

Comment: JPA is generating the query, I have no control. I am looking if JPA has any option to exclude identity column from Entity while generating query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the use of annotations @Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)? Why the generationtype is identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603638/what-is-the-use-of-annotations-id-and-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype)

Comment: Yes, It(Sequence Generation Startegy) works. But unfortunately I can not use this.

Comment: This works with other providers - I'm surprised Hibernate tries to insert 'default' when it doesn't need to pass in anything. You might be able to write your own behavior as described here https://dnikiforov.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/oracle-12c-identity-and-popular-orms/ or try another provider. Alternatively, a different generation strategy would be better. Preallocation is generally better performance for batch inserts, and using something like a UUID generator means no fetching it from the DB at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
Long id;
```

UPDATE: For a *view* on Oracle, use:

- `@Id @Generated` in Hibernate 6.2 (soon to be released), or
- the `SelectGenerator`, in either Hibernate 5 or 6.

But note that you will have to identify a `@NaturalId` of your entity, since otherwise Hibernate has no way of locating the just-inserted row to retrieve the generated id.

In your case, the natural id is the email address, I suppose.

Comment: This does not work with view(In Oracle DB). Getting below exception.

'ORA-32575: Explicit column default is not supported for modifying views'

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that your problem is a limitation of Oracle, and nothing at all to do with Hibernate?

Comment: Perhaps if you can first figure out what *SQL* works for inserting into this view, *then* we can help you figure out how to generate that SQL using Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, It can be limitation of Oracle which does not allow me to insert into a view. And I have no control over that.

Do we have any way in JPA using which we can tell JPA to not to include the primary key column while generating insert statement?

Comment: insert into home_view(email, first_name, last_name) values ('abc@gmail.com','abc','xyz');

The above SQL works for inserting into view.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle only supports identity columns as of version 12. You didn't mention which version you are using, but I guess this is the reason for the Oracle error. Either way, Oracle just recently stopped supporting versions older than 19c, so either you update or you have to use a different generation strategy i.e. sequence, table or uuid.