# How to persist Bidirectional one to one relational entities using Hibernate annotations?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have three tables Company,Contact and Address with bidirectional One to One relationship between (Company and Contact) and (Company and Address). The relationship is through foreign keys in the Owner of the relationship (Company).[image]

Company.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private String paymentTerms;
    private Address address;
    private Contact contact;

    public Company(){ }

    public Company(String companyName,String paymentTerms){
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.paymentTerms = paymentTerms;
    }

    @Id
    public int getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }
    public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getPaymentTerms() {
        return paymentTerms;
    }
    public void setPaymentTerms(String paymentTerms) {
        this.paymentTerms = paymentTerms;
    }
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_addressId",insertable=true,updatable=true,nullable=true,unique=true)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }   
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="contact_contactId",insertable=true,updatable=true,nullable=true,unique=true)
    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company [companyId=" + companyId + ", companyName="
                + companyName + ", paymentTerms=" + paymentTerms + ", address="
                + address + ", contact=" + contact + "]";
    }
}
```

Contact.java

```
   @Entity
public class Contact {

    private int contactId;
    private String contactPerson;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String landlineNumber;
    private Company company;

    public Contact(){}

    @Id 
    public int getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public void setContactId(int contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }   
    public String getContactPerson() {
        return contactPerson;
    }
    public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }
    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
    public String getLandlineNumber() {
        return landlineNumber;
    }
    public void setLandlineNumber(String landlineNumber) {
        this.landlineNumber = landlineNumber;
    }
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="contact")
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

Address.java

```
   @Entity
public class Address {

    private int addressId;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalCode;
    private Company company;

    public Address(){}

    public Address(String addressLine1,String addressLine2,String city,String state,String postalCode){
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    @Id
    public int getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }
    public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }   
    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }
    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }
    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }
    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }
    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="address")
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}

public void addCompany(Company company,Contact contact,Address address){
        try{
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("company");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            //address.setAddressId(company.getCompanyId());
            company.setAddress(address);
            company.setContact(contact);

            //contact.setContactId(company.getCompanyId());
            em.persist(address);
            em.persist(contact);
            em.persist(company);

            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        }catch(PersistenceException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I am getting the error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `fk_company_contact` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_contactId`) REFERENCES `contact` (`contactId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

```
`Apr 18, 2015 11:24:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;U:\EclipseJEE\eclipse;;.
Apr 18, 2015 11:24:57 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Struts 2 Portfolio' did not find a matching property.
Apr 18, 2015 11:24:58 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 18, 2015 11:24:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1502 ms
Apr 18, 2015 11:24:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 18, 2015 11:24:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ConverterFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.InterceptorFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ValidatorFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.UnknownHandlerFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DispatcherErrorHandler)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.ExcludedPatternsChecker)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:00 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.AcceptedPatternsChecker)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:02 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:02 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/68  config=null
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4427 ms
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:04 AM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'Login' in namespace: '/authentication'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:05 AM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'Login' in namespace: '/authentication'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:09 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor error
SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'login' on 'class authentication.Authentication: Error setting expression 'login' with value ['Login', ]
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:10 AM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'Logout' in namespace: '/home'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:10 AM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'Logout' in namespace: '/home'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:12 AM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'add' in namespace: '/company'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:13 AM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'add' in namespace: '/company'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:28 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:28 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:28 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:29 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: company
    ...]
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:31 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:33 AM org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl processProperties
WARN: HHH000059: Defining hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion=true ignored in HEM
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:35 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb]
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root}
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:37 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Apr 18, 2015 11:25:40 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Address
        (addressLine1, addressLine2, city, postalCode, state, addressId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Contact
        (contactPerson, email, landlineNumber, mobileNumber, contactId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        company
        (address_addressId, companyName, contact_contactId, paymentTerms, companyId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Apr 18, 2015 11:26:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
Apr 18, 2015 11:26:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `fk_company_contact` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_contactId`) REFERENCES `contact` (`contactId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
Apr 18, 2015 11:26:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Apr 18, 2015 11:26:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: SQL Warning Code: 1452, SQLState: 23000
Apr 18, 2015 11:26:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `fk_company_contact` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_contactId`) REFERENCES `contact` (`contactId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the entities have bidirectional relationships you are obliged to reference them back in `addCompany` method. This is related to the exception:

   > WARN: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
2. You don't use automatic *id generation* so you need to do it explicitly in your `addCompany` method for all the entities. Optionally you may let Hibernate do it for you by annotating get*Id() methods with `@GeneratedValue` and choose a suitable [id generation strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-hibernate)
3. Cascading the bidirectional relationships allows you to skip explicit persisting of entities on the non-owning side (`Contact` and `Address`)
4. Creating `EntityManagerFactory` multiple times adds a significant overhead to your application and should be avoided. Just create it only once and let `EntityManager` instances reuse it.
5. You may also consider creating `EntityManager` once for multiple invocations of `addMethod` (e.g. within addMethod's class or by injection)  and closing it only once when is no longer needed.

---

Move initialization of `emf` somewhere else:

```java
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("company"); // 4.
```

An updated version of `addCompany` method:

```java
em = emf.createEntityManager(); // 5.    
...
public void addCompany(Company company, Contact contact, Address address) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    company.setAddress(address);
    company.setContact(contact);

    contact.setCompany(company); // 1.
    address.setCompany(company); // 1.
    em.persist(company); // 3.

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
...
em.close(); // 5.
```

Comment: Not referencing the entities on both sides was the issue. And will follow your tips