# Postgresql manually inserted rows vs Hibernate save with sequence

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I've got an entity with @Id column when I have:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "user_accounts_id_seq")
public Long getId(){
    return id;
}
```

When I manually insert data into table by executing:

```
insert into user_accounts(id, name) values(1, "John");
```

I'm not using sequence but manually adding id equals to 1.

Then I create user account in Java by

```
UserAccount user = new UserAccount(null, "Paul") // where null => id
```

and save it with `UserAccountService's` method
`save` and get an error like there is duplicate in id key.

I am not sure if I understand the strategies well. I want to be able to add some values manually in database editor and then in program when saving if value with id exists hibernate should take next possible value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to mix *hand-made* ids with ids generated by the database. You should **avoid it as much as possible**.

## How sequences work

Let's say this is your table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_accounts
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(trim(name) > '')
) ;

-- The previous `CREATE` has actually worked as if it were defined like:
CREATE TABLE user_accounts
(
    -- Name of sequence = name of table || '_' || name of column || '_id'
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('user_accounts_id_seq'),
    name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(trim(name) > '')
) ;
```

At this point, you can actually check that one sequence has been created:

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.sequences;
```

```
sequence_catalog | sequence_schema             | sequence_name        | data_type | numeric_precision | numeric_precision_radix | numeric_scale | start_value | minimum_value | maximum_value       | increment | cycle_option
:--------------- | :-------------------------- | :------------------- | :-------- | ----------------: | ----------------------: | ------------: | :---------- | :------------ | :------------------ | :-------- | :-----------
postgres         | fiddle_sehahfpstptzxjchrypb | user_accounts_id_seq | bigint    |                64 |                       2 |             0 | 1           | 1             | 9223372036854775807 | 1         | NO
```

At this point, you can insert one row into the table, *without* specifying the value for column `id`, the `id` column will take its default value, which will be taken as `nextval` for the sequence named `user_accounts_id_seq`:

```
INSERT INTO user_accounts
    (name)
VALUES
    ('First inserted user account') ;
```

In a single user setup (nobody else doing anything at all with `user_accounts`), we'll have gotten `id = 1`:

```
SELECT * FROM user_accounts;
```

```
id | name                       
-: | :--------------------------
 1 | First inserted user account
```

You can now check he sequence current value, it is `1`:
    SELECT currval('user_accounts_id_seq') ;

```
| currval |
| ------: |
|       1 |
```

We can now do *weird things*. First we insert a row with explicit `NULL` value for id. It won't work in SQL (I don't know whether `Hibernate` might manipulate this `INSERT` by itself and *remove* the `NULL` and convert it to `DEFAULT`):

```
INSERT INTO user_accounts
    (id, name)
VALUES
    (NULL, 'It won''t work');
```

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, It won't work).
```

The sequence current value continues to be the same

```
SELECT currval('user_accounts_id_seq') ;
```

```
| currval |
| ------: |
|       1 |
```

At thsi point, we can insert a row with `id = 2`. It will work, because there's not any row with that `id` already in the table:

```
INSERT INTO user_accounts
    (id, name)
VALUES
    (2, 'Inserted a 2 id, it will work, but will produce problems');
```

```
1 rows affected
```

However, the sequence is *not* changed, and this will lead to later problems:

```
SELECT currval('user_accounts_id_seq') ;
```

```
| currval |
| ------: |
|       1 |
```

If we now try to insert with a sequence number, we will be out of luck, the sequence will give a `nextval` of 2 (`currval` + 1). As `id = 2` is already on the table, it will produce a `PK violation`:

```
INSERT INTO user_accounts
    (name)
VALUES
    ('This won''t work either, we broke the sequence');
```

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_accounts_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

You can see all the setup and experiment at: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=94c5b089e9176834c3ad96d8d1109c0d)*

---

## Workaround:

If you **really** need to both work with *automatically generated* `id`s and also with *manually generated* `id`s, the safest way is to make sure they are in ranges that *do not overlap*. For instance, reserve `id` 1 ... 10000 for manual input, and start your sequence at `10001` for automatic input.

```
CREATE TABLE user_accounts
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(trim(name) > '')
) ;
ALTER SEQUENCE user_accounts_id_seq RESTART WITH 10001 ;
```

I'd recommend not to try to have the database (via trigger or however) to use the next available `id` it tehre is a `PK violation`. You'll need to have `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level for it to work, or you still will have a high chance of having problems in concurrent scenarios.

Check it at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=abfc3ff032c59fc216b0dee0b3b81a66)*

Comment: As I described in my question I have exactly the same situation you described. So, there is no something automatic in Hibernate that compares sequence with ids checking if can write new entity ?

Comment: I don't know the internals of `hibernate` well enough, but I'd be shocked if any ORM would do such things behind-the-scenes. If you specify an `id`, it is because that's the one you want. If it cannot be, it is up to your code to decide what to do. Otherwise, `id` should be called `temptative_id`, and you should have a way to retrieve an `actual_id` it the temptative fails. Take a look at [How to choose the id generation strategy when using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate). Might help.

Comment: I had exactly same issue. Fixed ID column values with SQL command `UPDATE user_accounts SET id=(-1)*id;`. That simply turned all ID values to negative, which seems fine and does not overlap with hibernate sequence generator.

Answer (score 0):

If type of `id` is serial and `user_accounts_id_seq` is auto generated sequence for this attribute then for manually inserting use:

```
insert into user_accounts(name) values("John");
```

id will be getted from `user_accounts_id_seq` sequence.
So, you and hibernate will be use same `user_accounts_id_seq` sequence that warrants unique values for id.

Comment: Sometimes I need to put a liquibase script with data that depends on user_accounts table. So I must earlier know what id I inserted.

Comment: You may create trigger that will be set "correct" sequence `curval` (`=max(id) + 1`) after every inserting, but it is not good idea.