# Hibernate - Fetch a sequential number from database, preventing duplicated keys during concurrency

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

I have a situation maintaining a legacy project, using JSF / Primefaces / Hibernate, the database is DB2, the original code was migrated from Delphi to Java, but keeping the database structure since it came from a vendor (we can't change it). There are some tables used to fetch a sequential id (**SELECT MAX** and **UPDATE** after that).

The table structure has a composite key (year and number), the issue today is: we select the max number based on the year from a param table (which holds the "next sequential" value). Sometimes users using concurrently get the same number, causing errors when trying to persist duplicated keys.

I tried to implement a [Hibernate Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) to fetch and set the value during the `onSave` method, but I was unable to make it avoid the duplicated keys issue (Tried using it as `SessionFactory-scoped`). Also I tried to make the methods syncronized, but it didn't work also.

Is there a way to prevent this duplicated key issue (programmatically, without the need of changing the database) using Hibernate features?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you manage transactions in your application? BTW: your issue is not related to JSF.

Comment: Transactions are managed inside the `save` method, with `session.beginTransaction()` on the start of the method and `session.getTransaction().commit();` at the end

Comment: This question regarding sequence generation strategies may have answers and links interesting to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate