# Spring Boot foreign key entity null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys

`Spring Boot` version `2.1.6`.

I have `User` class :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long userID;
    String eMail;
    public User()
    {

    }
}
```

And a `LoginCredential` class :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class LoginCredential {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long userID;
    String eMail;
    String passwordHash;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    User user;
    public LoginCredential()
    {

    }
}
```

Shouldn't it create an instance of `User` when I create an instance of `LoginCredential`.

Cause I run this command : `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"a\", \"passwordHash\": \"b\" }" http://localhost:8080/login`

And I got an instance of `LoginCredential` **but not** of an `User`.

Response :

`{"userID":1,"passwordHash":"b","user":null,"email":"a"}`

And then I run this command : `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"c\", \"passwordHash\": \"d\" ,\"user\":{}}" http://localhost:8080/login`

And what I got is **nothing**, not of same ID.

Response :

`{"userID":2,"passwordHash":"d","user":{"userID":3,"email":null},"email":"c"}`

**Am I missing something ? How this can be resolved ?**

`LoginCredentialController` partially :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
LoginCredential newLoginCredential(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLoginCredential)
{   
    return repository.save(newLoginCredential);
}
```

My [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/V0R40E5j)

My [application.properties](https://pastebin.com/kmqGxsC1)

Comment: Post your curl requests response

Comment: You asked `Shouldn't it create an instance of User when I create an instance of LoginCredential?` That depends on what you are doing on your /login controller method. Please also post it here.

Comment: edited, please see @rimonmostafiz

Comment: Both results are exactly as expected - the first request does not contain a `User` so you receive no one, the second requests contains an empty `User` so you get one, but please consider that fact that the `LoginCredential#userID` has nothing to do with a `User#userID`.

Comment: @Smutje please see [this](https://youtu.be/qYTSCi6bh00?t=1030), just where I have set the starting. See he uses something that **creates child with the same id of parents **. I tried his code from git, and tutorial. doesn't work. And his tut doesn't even match with git code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, I later asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58229715/10305444) and found out an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58229877/10305444)

You have three problems

1. Lacking a `cascade` option to trigger `User` entity creation from `LoginCredential` save.
2. Lacking `@MapsId` annotation on `User` so that they share the same id, otherwise `LoginCredential` and its created `User` will have different id values for both of them has `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on their `@Id` columns
3. Not setting both sides of the relationship...

To fix all you need to change your entities to below (I also removed some useless annotations and values);

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    Long userID;

    @JsonBackReference
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID", referencedColumnName = "userID")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private LoginCredential loginCredential;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
public class LoginCredential {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long userID;
    String eMail;
    String passwordHash;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User user;
}
```

Also need to set both sides of the relationship before finalizing your endpoint;

```
Optional.ofNullable(loginCredential.getUser())
        .ifPresent(user -> user.setLoginCredential(loginCredential));
loginCredentialRepo.save(loginCredential);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Data
@Entity
public class LoginCredential implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long credentailID;
    String eMail;
    String passwordHash;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //<-- EAGER is default, but try setting it explicitly
    User user;
    public LoginCredential()
    {

    }
}



@PostMapping("/login")
LoginCredential newLoginCredential(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLoginCredential)
{   
    LoginCredential saveResult = repository.save(newLoginCredential);
    //load it again after saving 
    return repository.findbyId(saveResult.getuserId);
}
```

or better:

```
   @PostMapping("/login")
    ResponseEntity newLoginCredential(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLoginCredential)
    {   
      try{
        LoginCredential saveResult = repository.save(newLoginCredential);
        //load it again after saving 
        LoginCredential loaded = repository.findbyId(saveResult.getuserId);
//if you set a breakpoint here, you should already see if it is working, if its ok here, then it might have to do with serilalization ( jackson )...
            return new ResponseEntity<>(loaded,HttpStatus.OK);
          }
           catch (Exception e){
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                return       ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
            }
        }
```

and, do you have a dependency for jackson ? -> its responsible for serializing the object to json ...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and this in your properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=ALWAYS
```

hope that helps, cheers

Comment: Classes are annotated with `Entity` and `Data` too

Comment: so what should I do ? I couldn't get your answer

Comment: First of all there were a lot of error, in your code I fixed them. But it gave me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SANQT.png), just in a styled way. But see carefully there `id/userID` is different. The key is not working. @womd

Comment: ok, thx for fixing, should just illustrate basicly, but isn't this what you wanted ? - you get the UserCredentials with its Child User ....? .. the styled output comes from .intent_output=True , but the crucial thing is: spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=ALWAYS ... when the key's dont match - verify your database manually - are you sure its not saved that way ?

Comment: thanks for this much help, we are almost there. I have the child in parent right now. but I want their `userID/id` to be same.

Comment: @Maifee Ul Asad   - i would remove the userId from credentails or rename it to credentialId - if you want the id'S to be the same, you got to change ID-Stragegy for User-Entity to set it manually! since you told jpa/hibernate to generate ids itself, and it doese so on every save .... ( a quick an dirty would be to remove/recreate the tables and start from 1 with ids but that would only be temporarily correct ....-> see here for strategies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: I'm not clear with these `strategy`. Can you edit your answer please.

Comment: @Maifee Ul Asad  - i would just rename the field of userCredentail - when you need the userId you use   usercredentail.user.getId() - try clearing your table, it looks like the data is persiseted that way ....  you could verify with a manual query ... btw. what is your db ?