# TransientPropertyValueException in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have `LoginCredential` class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class LoginCredential implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   Long userID;
   String eMail;
   String passwordHash;
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   User user;
}
```

And here is my `User` class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   Long userID;
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = LoginCredential.class)
   @JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "userID")
   private LoginCredential loginCredential;
}
```

And my `LoginCredentialController`'s *POST*-ing method is simple :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
LoginCredential newLoginCredential(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLoginCredential) {
    logger.debug(newLoginCredential);
    LoginCredential a=repository.save(newLoginCredential);
    logger.debug(a);
    return a;
}
```

Now when I tried this command : `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"1\"}" http://localhost:8080/login`

I get a `LoginCredential` without any error, to be mentioned `user` field is `null`.

That's why I tried this command `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"1\",\"user\":{} }" http://localhost:8080/login`

Which gives me error saying :

> ```
> {
>   "status" : 500,
>   "error" : "Internal Server Error",
>   "message" : "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential.user -> com.mua.cse616.Model.User; org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential.user -> com.mua.cse616.Model.User",
>   "trace":....
> }
> ```

[Application.properties](https://pastebin.com/kmqGxsC1)

[pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/V0R40E5j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems

1. Lacking a `cascade` option to trigger `User` entity creation from `LoginCredential` save.
2. Lacking `@MapsId` annotation on `User` so that they share the same id, otherwise `LoginCredential` and its created `User` will have different id values for both of them has `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on their `@Id` columns
3. Not setting both sides of the relationship...

To fix all you need to change your entities to below (I also removed some useless annotations and values);

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    Long userID;

    @JsonBackReference
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID", referencedColumnName = "userID")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private LoginCredential loginCredential;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
public class LoginCredential {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long userID;
    String eMail;
    String passwordHash;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User user;
}
```

Also need to set both sides of the relationship before finalizing your endpoint;

```
Optional.ofNullable(loginCredential.getUser())
        .ifPresent(user -> user.setLoginCredential(loginCredential));
loginCredentialRepo.save(loginCredential);
```

Comment: Not working - when I tried `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"1\"}" http://localhost:8080/login` It gave me **"attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential.user]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attem
pted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential.user]"**

Comment: can you see [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qACd37mSwn0I0nk0LXvHW6jgBqvvgyz_/view?usp=sharing) please ..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad ah of course, that is due to infinite recursion loop. Updated answer, check `@JsonBackReference` & `@JsonManagedReference`. When you try to print `LoginCredential`, it tries to print `User`, then that `User` tries to print `LoginCredential` again, then that tries to print `User` again, creating this endless recursive call stack until it kills everything.

Comment: It gives me error : **"attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.mua.cse616.Model.User.loginCredential]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attem
pted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.mua.cse616.Model.User.loginCredential]"** 

see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myuE3.png)

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad that does not happen in my local, are you sure you copied everything from my answer? I get `{"userID":1,"passwordHash":null,"user":null,"email":"hey"}` back when I pass `{"email": "hey"}`. It seems you are inserting an empty `User` in `LoginCredential`, either keep it null, or do `user.setLoginCredential()`

Comment: I copied exactly the same... error *message* is **"No message available"** and trace is something like this : **java.lang.StackOverflowError\r\n\tat com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential.toString...** do I need to override toString method ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad no no, that is because of that stack overflow case I told you, why are you trying to print an entity? Just return it in your controller method, should be OK. Otherwise try to use `@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper` to print it, do `System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginCredential))`. With `@JsonBackReference` & `@JsonManagedReference` annotations, jackson fixes that recursion issue. But `toString()` will still throw that error.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad you already fixed every issue, just `toString()` issue, just put `@ToString(exclude = "loginCredential")` from lombok on `User` class

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@GeneratedValue` for User object

Add `CascadeType` for  OneToOne

By doing this you tell hibernate to save User to the database when saving `LoginCredential`.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class LoginCredential implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   Long userID;

   String eMail;

   String passwordHash;

   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   User user;
}
```

Refer this for [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be)

Comment: Blues are what I'm receiving , red saving, yellow getting.. user is null.. please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCNqf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make User class Serializable as well.

Comment: User should not be null inside Login Credential object. while you receiving in newLoginCredential(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLoginCredential) method