# JPA repository retrieve custom primary key value after save

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class pointing to postgresql table. Below is table structure. The paymentreferencenumber is the PK which is populated by a trigger. id field is the sequence generated field. When i try to save in this table using JPARepository save method it inserts the first record. But after that it fails due to the primary key constraint. Since PK is a string type and generated using trigger I am specifying generator strategy as 'select'. Can anyone help me with this blocker and point me in the right direction. Thanks

Table structure --

```
custId serial not null,
    paymentreferencenumber varchar(32) not null
        constraint customers1_pkey
            primary key,
    firstname varchar(255),
    lastname varchar(255)

Entity class --
@Entity
@Table(name = "customersnew")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;


    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
    @GenericGenerator(name="seq", strategy="sequence", parameters = { @Parameter(name="key", value = "customersnew_custid_seq")})
    @Column(name = "custid")
    private long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "trigger_generated")
    @GenericGenerator(name="trigger_generated", strategy="select", parameters = { @Parameter(name="key", value = "id")})
    @Column(name = "paymentreferencenumber")
    private String refNum;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

}

--- Controller using JPA save

@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public CustomerController(CustomerRepository repository, EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String create(@RequestBody CustomerUI customer){
        // save a single Customer

        Customer returnObj = repository.saveAndFlush(new Customer(customer.getFirstName(), customer.getLastName()));

        PersistenceUnitUtil util = emf.getPersistenceUnitUtil();

        Object retObj = util.getIdentifier(returnObj);

        return "Customer is created";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an id generation strategy, Hibernate will use `GenerationType.AUTO`. This will result in any of

> AUTO - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the
>   underlying DB.

If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-hibernate), you'll notice all of those generate ids of type `long`, `short` or `int`, not of type `String`.

Say you wanted a `String` UUID as an id, you could use

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "paymentreferencenumber")
private String refNum;
```